# Wrong number of arguments (2 for 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

it is the first time to encounter this error in rails and i really don't know where is it coming from here is the function implementation :

```
   def self.send (sender,recivers,content)
            recivers.each do |reciver|
                @notification = Notification.new
                @notification.sender= sender
                @notification.user = reciver
                @notification.body = content 
                @notification.save
            end 

    end
```

and here is how am calling it :

```
def after_create(announcment)
    instructor_id = announcment.course.instructor_id
    sender = User.find_by_id(instructor_id)
    students = announcment.course.users
    body = announcment.announcment
    coures_name = announcment.course.name 
    Notification.send(sender,students,body)
    UserMailer.notify_students_course(students,coures_name)
end
```

Comment: post your error log pls

Comment: i found the error it was in the name of the method send but i dont know why would it create an error is send a reserved keyword ?

Comment: @mohamed It's a Ruby `Object` class method (so every class inherits it) that calls the method named with first argument and parameters the rest of the arguments given to `send`. Also in RoR its a [reserverd word](http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words)

Comment: Better not overriding it.

Comment: @RodrigoMartinez thanks for the explanation ^_^

Comment: @RodrigoMartinez wouldn't it be good to have your comment as an answer, so it can be marked? Otherwise it looks like this question is unanswered.

Comment: @pascalbetz Thanks for the recommendation :)

Comment: @mohamed, just added the answer if it was enough for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`send` is a Ruby method from `Object` class (so every class inherits it) that calls the method named with first argument and parameters the rest of the arguments given to `send`. Also in RoR its a [reserverd word](http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words).

Better not overriding it, because it can get messy.